# Processing both elements when they may or may not have a parent child relationship

Tags: xslt

This seems like a very fundamental question but I've the last few days searching for an answer and experiementing to no avail. I'm trying to turn this:

```
<bold> bang </bold> 
<line> I was walking down the street </line> 
<line> when I heard a <bold> bang </bold></line>
```

into:

```
<strong> bang </strong> 
<textline> I was walking down the street </textline> 
<textline> when I heard a <strong> bang </strong></textline>
```

using this:

```
<xsl:template name="first" match="//line">
    <textline>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </textline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="second" match="//bold">
    <strong>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()|line|bold">
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|line|bold"
        />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that it either hits the `<bold>` OR the `<line>` tag, but not both. e.g.:

```
<strong> bang </strong> 
<textline> I was walking down the street </textline> 
<textline> when I heard a bang </textline>
```

If the `<bold>` tag was always within `<line>`, or never within it, it would be straight forward.

I tried adding a more specific template which I thought would get priority:

```
<xsl:template name="third" match="//l/bold">
    <strong>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </strong>
</xsl:template>
```

But it still doesn't give the desired results. I strongly suspect my error is due to a misunderstanding of something fundamental about the language, but searching around I can't find any solution Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `value-of` in the specific templates, use `apply-templates`.  You want recursive processing of tags to continue after you've matched one set.

Comment: When I change any of the value-ofs to apply-templates I get an error, saying it's an infinite loop. I'm using a saxon 9.04 engine.

Comment: Apologies, I had left the select="." portion when replacing the value-of tags. Thanks for that, that was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="bold">
     <strong><xsl:apply-templates/></strong>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
     <textline><xsl:apply-templates/></textline>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided XML fragment, wrapped into a single top element to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <bold> bang </bold>
    <line> I was walking down the street </line>
    <line> when I heard a <bold> bang </bold></line>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<strong> bang </strong>
<textline> I was walking down the street </textline>
<textline> when I heard a <strong> bang </strong></textline>
```